# Storage of local constants in C

Tags: c, linker, elf

I have a question regarding storage of constants in C.

If I have the following statement:

```
const int a = 5;
```

If the statement was in global scope, the constant would be stored in .rodata .
I have been working with the TI compiler for MSP430 devices. If the statement was in local scope, the constant is stored on the stack .

I am not sure what would happen if I declare it as a "static const" in local scope, but I would expect it to be stored in .rodata .

Is this behavior correct?

Comment: I don't know about the TI compiler, but most compilers will treat `const int a = 5;` similar to a `#define a 5` and not store it anywhere in particular.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "correct" behavior. Platform, toolchain type and version, OS, compiler and linker settings have all huge influence on the section a variable will end up in.

I have seen `static const` being put in `.text`, `.data`, `.sdata`, etc.